# How to get the name of an object to call a class method if I don't know the name?

Tags: java

I have a class called AttendanceSystem:

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> student = new LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>();

public AttendanceSystem(String s){
    student.add(new LinkedList<String>());
    student.get(student.size()-1).add(s);
}

public void setEmail(String d){
     student.get(student.size()-1).add(d);
}
```

In my main I have this:

```
System.out.println("Please enter your ID.");
String s = keyboard.nextLine();      
new AttendanceSystem(s);

System.out.println("Please enter your Email.");
String d = keyboard.nextLine();
```

I want to add more elements into the object but since I used `new AttendanceSystem(s)` I don't know the name of the object I created so I cannot simply do `objectname.setEmail(s)`. How can I call a method to that very object? Or is there a better way to do this?

I am using a scanner so I can keep adding new objects automatically until I tell it to stop.

UPDATED:

My main now:

```
  LinkedList<AttendanceSystem> list = new LinkedList<AttendanceSystem>();

System.out.println("Please enter your ID.");
String s = keyboard.nextLine();      
list.add(new AttendanceSystem(s));

System.out.println("Please enter your Email.");
String d = keyboard.nextLine();    
list.get(list.size()-1).setEmail(d);
```

I stored all the objects in a linked list so I can just do this `list.get(list.size()-1).setEmail(d);`.

Comment: Why not just assign the new object to a variable: `AttendanceSystem aSystem = new AttendanceSystem(s);` ?

Comment: Why not keep a reference to the newly created `AttendanceSystem`?

Comment: The real question is why you need to setEmail if the constructor takes the email as parameter??

Comment: @RC. I think the constructor takes the `ID`.

Comment: @ManosNikolaidis Sorry I forgot to mention I am using a scanner so I can keep adding new objects automatically until i stop it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply:

```
AttendanceSystem identiferName = new AttendanceSystem(s);
```

then use the `setEmail` to set the relevant data for that object.

EDIT

you might want to create an `addAttendee` method which will take the `ID` and `Email` then simply add it to the `LinkedList` inside the `AttendanceSystem` class.

```
public void addAttendee(String id, String email){
       LinkedList<String> myList = new LinkedList<>();
       myList.add(id);
       myList.add(email);
       this.student.add(myList);
}
```

**note** - in this case, you should just get rid of the constructor parameter & don't use it to add any IDs or Emails.

With does changes in mind and considering that you don't want to store a reference to a new object, you call it like this:

```
new AttendanceSystem().addAttendee(id,email);
```

Comment: Hi. Sorry I forgot to mention I am using a scanner so I can keep adding new objects automatically until I stop it.

Comment: @JohnP. the solution i've recommended should still work, but it would be better to create an `addAttendance` method.

Comment: The id and email are supposed to be entered using the scanner. But anyway I found the solution to my problem. I updated my post. You can take a look if you want. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @JohnP. that's what the solution does.

Comment: You're right. Sorry bout that, didn't read it properly. But which method would you say is better, mine or yours?

Comment: @JohnP. They are both decent ways of doing it, so there would _not_ be a major benefit (if any). ^^.